# I am using wix3.6 Instance Transform feature. My requirement is to spit the output in 2 different folder based upon instance transform id selected

Tags: c#, service, wix

I am using wix3.6 Instance Transform feature. My requirement is to spit the output in 2 different folder based upon instance TRANSFERCATEGORY property provided via command prompt.  I am not getting this property in my wxs and it is always going to else part.

```
<Property Id="INSTANCEID" Value="0" />
        <InstanceTransforms Property="INSTANCEID">
            <Instance Id="LastValue" ProductCode="{ED59B2D8-9A9B-4934-B3A5-7EC6A5A7854A}" ProductName="Value" />
            <Instance Id="Series" ProductCode="{BE7644EA-322F-4756-863B-605B753720C1}" ProductName="Series" />
        </InstanceTransforms>

<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
            <Directory Id="ProgramFiles64Folder">
                <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER1" Name="$(var.Manufacturer)">
                    <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER2" Name="ParentFolder">                     
                        <?if [TRANSFERCATEGORY] = "Series"  ?>
                        <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="Series">
                            <Directory Id="ServiceInstaller" Name="ServiceInstaller" />
                        </Directory>
                        <?elseif [TRANSFERCATEGORY] = "LastValue"?>
                        <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="LastValue">
                            <Directory Id="ServiceInstaller" Name="ServiceInstaller" />
                        </Directory>
                        <?endif?>
                    </Directory>
                </Directory>
            </Directory>
        </Directory>    

msiexec /i RDStoGMS.Installer.msi TRANSFORMS=":LastValue" TRANSFERCATEGORY="LastValue"
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you mix a compile time construct with a runtime construct.
You could use the SetDirectory custom action s.t. like:

```
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
  <Directory Id="ProgramFiles64Folder">
    <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER1" Name="$(var.Manufacturer)">
      <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER2" Name="ParentFolder">                     
        <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="Series">
          <Directory Id="ServiceInstaller" Name="ServiceInstaller" />
        </Directory>                            
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
  </Directory>
</Directory> 

<SetDirectory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Value="[TRANSFERCATEGORY]">TRANSFERCATEGORY</SetDirectory>
```

This would overwrite the default 'Series' with the value of TRANSFERCATEGORY if defined.